# How to combines two mappings into one in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

I have two keymaps like this

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n","te","<C-w>l|ia.exe<CR>")
vim.keymap.set('n', 'c', ':w <bar> !gcc "%" -o "~/Newfolder/nvimoutput/a.exe"<CR><CR>', { silent = true })
```

I need to combine them both into something like this

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n","cf","{how do i do this part now?}")
```

I tried 'bar' and '|' between them but it didnt work maybe its not using cmd mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply concatenate both:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n","cf",'<C-w>l|ia.exe<CR>:w <bar> !gcc "%" -o "~/Newfolder/nvimoutput/a.exe"<CR><CR>')
```

Mappings are executed in the starting mode (here `Normal`) and is just a list of key strokes to be sent.

Comment: thanks that helped!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If it solves the problem maybe you could accept the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest ans rassure others that is worth trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without Lua, a sane solution would be

```
:nmap cf tec
```

where we use `nmap` because we *want* recursive mapping interpretations (we want `tec` to be interpreted as mappings, if possible).